# Pass input value as parameter in Ajax ActionLink MVC call

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I've spent all day searching high and low for an answer to my problem and just can't find one.
Can someone please suggest a simple way I can get the value of the input field as a parameter in my Ajax call?
I would rather it stayed as an @Ajax.ActionLink call if possible.
Thanks.

```
<div class="form-group ui-widget">
    <input class="form-control" id = "Reference" type = "text" />
</div>
<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Select","SelectedReference","Home",
                     new { reference = ?????????? },
                     new AjaxOptions
                     {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        UpdateTargetId = "Results",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        OnBegin = "OnBeforeReference",
                        OnFailure = "OnAjaxError",
                        OnSuccess = "hideReference"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                       id = "referenceSelectButton",
                       @class = "btn btn-success"
                    })
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get the value of the input field as a parameter in my Ajax call?

No, It's not possible to use `@Ajax.ActionLink` to fulfil your requirements.

Alternatively, You can use `jQuery` `ajax` to do this.

Just use a simple button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="referenceSelectButton">Select</button>
```

And on button click use `jQuery` `ajax` request to do all your work done.

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#referenceSelectButton').click(function () {
    var referenceVal = $('#Reference').val();
    $.ajax('@Url.Action("SelectedReference","Home",new { reference="-1"})'.replace('-1', referenceVal), {
        method: 'post',
        beforeSend:OnBeforeReference,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#Results').html(response);
            hideReference();
        },
        error: OnAjaxError,
    });
});
</script>    
}
```

I have placed the jquery script code inside `@section` so that It's placed after jQuery scripts. Hopefully, this will resolve your problem.